# ESP-IDF How to ckeck if task is already running?

Tags: c++, c, esp32, rtos, esp-idf

I have a job that should be ran with minimum interval of 5 seconds. Trigger that starts this job can be executed in any moment and in any frequency.

What is the best way to solve such a case in RTOS environment?

I want to make a function that creates a task if it does not exist. Existing task should wait for minimum interval to pass before doing anything. While it is waiting, function that should create it should skip the creation of a new task.

What is the right way to check if task was created but didn't finish yet?
Should I use tasks at all in this case?

Code example below:

```
#define CONFIG_MIN_INTERVAL 5000

uint32_t last_execution_timestamp = 0;
TaskHandle_t *task_handle = NULL;
bool task_done = true;

static void report_task(void *context)
{
    if (esp_timer_get_time() / 1000 < last_execution_timestamp + CONFIG_MIN_INTERVAL)
    {
        ESP_LOGI(stateTAG, "need to wait for  for right time");
        int time_to_wait = last_execution_timestamp + CONFIG_MIN_INTERVAL - esp_timer_get_time() / 1000;
        vTaskDelay(time_to_wait / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
    }

    // do something...

    task_done = true;
    vTaskDelete(task_handle);
}

void init_report_task(uint32_t context)
{    
    if (!task_done)
    {
        ESP_LOGI(stateTAG, "TASK already exists");
    }
    else
    {
        ESP_LOGI(stateTAG, "Creating task");
        xTaskCreate(&report_task, "report_task", 8192, (void *)context, 4, task_handle);
        task_done = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[eTaskGetState](https://www.freertos.org/a00021.html#eTaskGetState) can be used to check if a task is already running, but such a solution can be susceptible to races. For example your task is technically still "running" when it's in fact "finishing", i.e. setting `task_done = true;` and preparing for exit.

A better solution could be to use a [queue](https://www.freertos.org/Embedded-RTOS-Queues.html) (or a [semaphore](https://www.freertos.org/Embedded-RTOS-Binary-Semaphores.html)) and have the task run continuously, waiting for the messages to arrive and processing them in a loop.

Using a [semaphore](https://www.freertos.org/a00113.html), you can do `xSemaphoreTake(sem, 5000 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);` to wait for either a wake-up condition or a timeout of 5 seconds, whichever comes first.

== EDIT ==

> *if there is no events task should wait. Only if event happens it should run the job. It should run it immediately if there was no execution in past 5 seconds. If there was an execution it should wait until 5 seconds since last execution and only then run it*

You can achieve that by carefully managing the semaphore's ticks to wait. Something like this (untested):

```
TickType_t nextDelay = portMAX_DELAY;
TickType_t lastWakeup = 0;
const TickType_t minDelay = 5000 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS;

for (;;) {
    bool signalled = xSemaphoreTake(sem, nextDelay);
    TickType_t now = (TickType_t)(esp_timer_get_time() / (portTICK_PERIOD_MS * 1000));
    if (signalled) {
        TickType_t ticksSinceLastWakeup = now - lastWakeup;
        if (ticksSinceLastWakeup < minDelay) {
            // wakeup too soon - schedule next wakeup and go back to sleep
            nextDelay = minDelay - ticksSinceLastWakeup;
            continue;
        }
    }
    lastWakeup = now;
    nextDelay = portMAX_DELAY;
    
    // do work ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In my case job should not be executed every 5 seconds.  if there is no events task should wait. Only if event happens it should run the job. It should run it immediately if there was no execution in past 5 seconds. If there was an execution it should wait until 5 seconds since last execution and only then run it.

Comment: That's a key piece of information what was unclear in the question. See my edit.